# How do I sign a short text message with ~/.ssh/id_{dsa,ecdsa,ed25519}?

Tags: ssh, asymmetric, openssh, dsa

There are already a number of questions about reusing SSH keys for something else:

- [Converting keys between openssl and openssh](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32768/converting-keys-between-openssl-and-openssh)
- [How to use public key in ~/.ssh for asymmetrical encryption with OpenSSL](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36632/how-to-use-public-key-in-ssh-for-asymmetrical-encryption-with-openssl)
- https://superuser.com/questions/576506/how-to-use-ssh-rsa-public-key-to-encrypt-a-text
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12260/how-to-encrypt-messages-text-with-rsa-using-openssl
- https://gist.github.com/colinstein/de1755d2d7fbe27a0f1e

but they all seem to deal only with RSA keys.

How do I "misuse" `id_{dsa,ecdsa,ed25519}` for something non-networked, such as signing some [short] text file? How do I verify such signature with id_*.pub?

Answer (score 2):

For DSA, ECDSA using OpenSSL and using different functions and structures than for RSA.

It won't work for ed25519 keys, because their operations are [implemented in the openSSH itself](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ed25519.c). But you can again reuse OpenSSH code and check how the sing & verify works there. You would also need to use OpenSSH parser, because the ED25519 keys are stored in the [new OpenSSH format](http://www.tedunangst.com/flak/post/new-openssh-key-format-and-bcrypt-pbkdf), instead of standard PEM.